# casperjs does not find popup selector

Tags: javascript, popup, casperjs

I have a casperjs script that logs into a page and then clicks a "watch video" button,upon which a popup with video is launched. Then I try to switch to the context of the popup using casper.withPopup. However I am unable to print the url of the popup as well as clicking the play button.
Seems I am not getting into the DOM context of the popup.

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.options.waitTimeout = 90000;

casper.userAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.109 Safari/537.36');

casper.viewport = {width: 1366, height: 768}; 

var x = require('casper').selectXPath;


url1 = '--------';

casper.start(url1, function() {
this.sendKeys("#email","----");
this.sendKeys("#password","---");


casper.wait(1000);
});
casper.thenClick(x('/html/body/section/div/div/form/div/div/div[3] /input'));


// use XPAth

casper.thenClick(x('/html/body/nav/div/ul/li[2]/a'),function() { 


casper.wait(700,function() {
console.log('waited 700 ms');

pres_preurl = this.getCurrentUrl();
console.log('url before video:'+pres_preurl);

});
});



casper.then(function() {

this.clickLabel("Watch");

console.log('watch');
casper.wait(90000);

this.withPopup(/popup/, function() {

this.waitForSelector('video[id="video"]',function() {
this.evaluate(function() {
    console.log(this.getCurrentUrl());
    document.querySelector('video[id="video"]').click();
    });
});
});
});




casper.run();
```

Comment: Why are you using `casper.page.onPageCreated` (switching into a PhantomJS style script) instead of using `casper.withPopup`?

Comment: hm, I should probably go that way, thanks

Comment: If you do that, then you can use the usual `casper.waitForSelector` function to wait for the selector. Anyway, check whether the element is in an iframe. You can also take screenshots along the way to see where it goes wrong and whether you're on the correct page.

Comment: I tried to use casper.on('popup-created') and casper.on('popup.loaded') but then it is not possible to obtain the url of the loaded popup, http://pastebin.com/fC1pAWDe

Comment: As I said, you should use `casper.withPopup`